# Woocommerce Hide Shipping method based on category

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to disabel/hide a shipping method based on a category in Woocommerce (2.1.12).

I successfully achieved hiding a paymeny method using this function:

```
function filter_gateways($gateways){
    $category_ID = array('14');  // <----------- add the ids for which u want to turn off "cash on delivery"

    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ID ) ) {
                unset($gateways['cod']);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $gateways;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','filter_gateways');
```

However, disabling a shipping method seems not to be working.
I tried three different snippets.

No.1 (not working):

```
function custom_shipping_methods( $available_methods ) { 
    $category_ID = array('14');  // <----------- add the ids for which u want to turn off "local pickup"

    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ID ) ) {
                unset( $available_methods['local_pickup'] );
                break;
            }
            break;
         }
     }
     return $available_methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'custom_shipping_methods' );
```

No.2 (not working):

```
function custom_shipping_methods( $is_available ) { 

    $category_ID = array('14');  // <----------- add the ids for which u want to turn off "local pickup"

    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ID ) ) {
                $is_available = false;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $is_available;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_local_pickup_is_available', 'custom_shipping_methods' );
```

No.3 (not working) I tried this because apparently newer versions of woocommerce use the filter below:

```
function hide_local_pickup( $rates, $package ) {

    $category_ID = array('14');  // <----------- add the ids for which u want to turn off "local pickup"

    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ID ) ) {
            unset( $rates['local_pickup'] );
            break;
            }
        break;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_local_pickup' , 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar request and combined your solution with some others that I found and got what you need working.

Apparently woocommerce doesn't include tags or categories in the cart array, so you have to go get it first, then do your function.

Here is a working function below to unset the 'local_pickup' from the available shipping methods:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_based_on_tag' ,    10, 1 );

function check_cart_for_share() {

// specify the category id's you want to hide local_pickup
 $category_ID = array(
    '6', // books
    '7', // prints
    '13', // candles
    '8', // note cards
    '9', // origonal art
 );
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;

$found = false;

// loop through the array looking for the categories. Switch to true if the category is found.
  foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ID ) ) {

        $found = true;
        break;
    }
  }
}

return $found;

}

function hide_shipping_based_on_tag( $available_methods ) {

// use the function above to check the cart for the categories.
if ( check_cart_for_share() ) {

    // remove the method you want
    unset( $available_methods['local_pickup'] ); // Replace "local_pickup" with the shipping option that you want to remove.
}

// return the available methods without the one you unset.
return $available_methods;

}
```